# Value of $k$ for which integral takes minimum value

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, optimization, improper-integrals

Find the value of $k$ for which the value of given integral is minimum:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{2+4x+3x^2+5x^3+3x^4+4x^5+2x^6}.dx$$

Could someone give me hint as how to begin this question? I am not able to get the initial thought.

Comment: Is the value k=4

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I don't have the answer.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: that is not true. The minimum is achieved at $k=2$.

Comment: Oh yes i forgot to equate. what i did was dividing and multiplying by x^6 and then setting x^(-1)=u  thus equating the reduced and given polynomial's degree of numerator to get $6-k-2=k $ thus $k=2$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar how does equating exponents gives maximum value of integral?

Answer (score 5):

The denominator of the integrand function is a palyndromic polynomial, hence
$$ I_k = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{k-3}\,dx}{q\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\stackrel{x\to x^{-1}}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{1-k}\,dx}{q\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}=I_{4-k} $$
with $q(z)=2z^3+4z^2-3z-3=(z-1)(3+6z+2z^2)$. The minimum for $I_k$ is so:

$$ \color{blue}{\large I_2} = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x\,q\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}=2\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{q(z)\sqrt{z^2-4}}=0.06822013435\ldots $$

Comment: would you help out a poor physicist and explain a bit what palyndromic is and how we can use it here?

Comment: @tired: a palyndromic polynomial is a polynomial whose sequence of coefficients is palyndromic, i.e. can be reversed and stays the same. $2+5z+2z^2$, $2+7z+8z^2+8z^3+7z^4+2z^5$ are palyndromic polynomials. The next step is to exploit the fact that $x^n+x^{-n}$ is always a polynomial in the variable $x+x^{-1}$.

Comment: thx, nice technique (+1)

Comment: Very nice! (+1)